# VB.NET: What is the equivalent of the SQL Server bit datatype?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a field in a SQL Server table that is of type `bit`.

When I try to use a `Boolean` in `VB.NET` when passing parameters to a stored procedure, there are never any matches. I have also tried passing an integer to the stored procedure and that does not work either.

Comment: Pls. post a code sample. c# bool & SQL Server bit works for me.

Comment: I should also mention that this is vb.net 2003
and sql 2000 asp.net application

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have a look at this table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SqlDbType.Bit
```

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.aspx)